# Accidentally erased SSD with "dd", any chance of recovery?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, dd

I was trying to clone a SSD last night and made a very simple, stupid mistake.

Instead of doing `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda`, I did the reverse, `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

Essentially I read from a brand new SSD (which wasn't formatted at all, essentially all blank data) and wrote it on top of my old SSD with all my data.

I've read different reports about recovering data, but most of those apply only to hard drives because of how sectors work, and SSDs are still a fairly new technology.

Without having to send the drive off to some lab somewhere, am I basically out of luck as far as recovering anything off it? It was formatted as NTFS and running Windows 7.

And this, folks, is why you should not try to copy sensitive data when tired, in case you do something stupid like mixing up drive names ;)

Comment: You are out of luck.  The media type doesn't really matter.

Comment: How data is handled on a SSD is basically the same as with your traditional mechanical data. Data is written, data is read, when data is deleted its flagged to indicate it was deleted. In both cases file recovery only depends if the data was written over with new data.  Based on the additional information in the comments ( the fact the source drive was larger then the destination drive is important ) data recovery won't be possible.

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: [When a solid state drive fails, can the data still be recovered?](http://superuser.com/questions/192661/when-a-solid-state-drive-fails-can-the-data-still-be-recovered)

Comment: DD is called DestroyDisk for a reason. Your operation as described would have destroyed the data beyond any reasonable means of recovery regardless of the disk type. I'm thinking the lab would have trouble with this one, though they probably have a few tricks up their sleeves. Sorry man

Comment: `dd` is not DestroyDisk, it is Data Description.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two SSDs were the same size, you are out of luck.

If the source was smaller than the destination, you have a small amount of hope as some data on the end of the disk may have been preserved, but that would be a large recovery effort.

As far as I know, there is no way to recover overwritten data on an SSD (HDDs are iffy anyway)...

Comment: Yes - in fact, the new one was larger. So it attempted to copy a bigger drive to a smaller one and obviously stopped when it reached the end of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a zeroed disk, there is nothing to recover. Without a full-blown forensics team working on it, it would be nearly impossible to recover anything from it, as far as I know. It sucks, but it's just the way it works. I hope you had backups of anything important. Good luck!

It is theoretically possible, based on the amount of wear on the individual transistors on the SSD's flash chip(s), to guess to some degree what was on the disk in some circumstances. But this is basically impossible without an electron microscope and, again, a forensics team.

Comment: Well, it was a brand new SSD I had just bought from the store, no partition table on it or anything.  Wouldn't dd essentially see it as all zeroes? I'm really not sure how it would show up, all I know is that it copied a bunch of blank data to my good drive.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't even formatted and didn't have a partition table, `dd` would see all zeroes when it was read.